# The difference between a fiber and a section of a vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, vector-bundles

If  $ E_x := \pi^{-1}(x) $ is the fiber over $x$ where $(E,\pi,M)$ is the vector bundle. And the section is $s: M \to E $ with $\pi \circ s = id_M $. This implies that $\pi^{-1} = s $ on $M$. So then whats the difference between a fiber over $x$ and the section restricted to $x$.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question. The fiber of a vector bundle is a vector space, and a section is a copy of $M$ inside of the bundle. They are complerely different objecs. And, it is not true that $\pi^{-1}=s$--$\pi$ is not invertible. It has a right inverse, any section, which means it's surjective, but it is certainly not injective (unless the bundle is trivial of rank $0$).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A section is a choice of a particular element from each fiber. That is, $s(x) \in E_x$. Thus if we have a section $s$ and we restrict it to a point $x$, then we get a single vector from the fiber $E_x$. On the other hand, the fiber $E_x$ is generally more than a single vector (it's a vector space).

Comment: So a single co-vector with its base point is a section of $T^*M$ whereas the fiber is a field of co-vector?

Comment: A single co-vector with its base point would be a section of $T^*M$ restricted to a single point. Remember (in this case) a section is a map $s:M \to T^*M$. This map associates to each point $x \in M$ a co-vector $s(x) \in T^*_x M$. So you're basically right, but you need to include all the basepoints rather than just one for it to be a section.

A fiber (at a point x) is the vector space ($T^*_x M$) where these co-vectors live.

Answer (score 2):

A fibre is a set and a section is a map. The fibre over $x$ is the set $\pi^{-1}(x)$ and the section is the map $s:M\to E$

Comment: Sorry, I mean whats the difference between the image of the section restricted to $x$ and and the fiber over $x$.

Comment: I'm not sure what it means the image of the section restricted to $x$. You mean $s(x)$? We have that $\pi(s(x))=x$ and so $s(x)\in E_x$

Answer (score 1):

A section is *any* function s that assigns to every point p in the base an element in its fiber $E_p$ The restriction s(p) assigns to p a point in $E_p$. As an example, a section of the tangent bundle is a vector field, i.e., an assignment of a tangent vector to each tangent space $T_pM$; its restriction to p assigns to p a tangent vector $X_p \in T_pM$  . The fiber over a point $p$ is the inverse image of $p$ under the specific map $\pi$. In a vector bundle, this fiber is a vector space. In the same example of the tangent bundle to a manifold $M$ , with $\pi(x,p)=p$ , $\pi^{-1}(p)=T_pM$.